# Best way to setup lists

Tags: drupal, civimember, evaluating-civicrm

I am familiar with Drupal and just evaluating Civicrm and having looked around not sure of the best way to do something basic so before going too far though I would check.

I need to manage a membership and the out of the box functionality is fine and getting to grips with that. However when a membership is defined for a user I they can choose to be members of one or more clubs. The list of clubs has associated data (such as location, committee members, url etc) which is managed by the club. Each club is also a member of a region.

I know how I would create this data in Drupal but just wondering the best way with Civicrm.

So what I am after is;

Region (each region can modify the basic data for the region)
  Region A
  Region B
  Region C

Club (each club can modify the basic data for the region. The club needs to select one or more regions to be members of)
  Club 1
  Club 2
  Club 3

Membership need the member to be able to select one of more clubs to be a member of.

Creating the Region and Club in Drupal is straight forward but if I want the club to be listed for the member data what is the best way to do all of this?

Sorry if this is a basic question but just haven't been able to work out the best way so far.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I would make region and club to be Organization sub-type and make a relationship between club and region. 
So you can use the contact fields for the address info and url and if you need you can add custom fields to each subtype.

Then there are 2 options imo:

- Create a membershiptype per club, where each club is the Membership Organization.
- Create a custom field of type Contact Reference and add it to the Memberships, where you can select a Club for each membership

Both have advantages and disadvantages. I suggest you try them and see for yourself.